# How to get name of class that implements interface?

Tags: c#, .net

How to get name of class that implements interface ?

```
interface IHuman
{
    public int Weight { get => 0; }
    public void ShowInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"I am a {here must be name of class that implements this interface} and my weight is {Weight} kg.");
    }
}
```

Comment: There could be thousands of classes that implement an interface…

Comment: Create a new class, implement the interface, implement the method and write your own Console.WriteLine in that method with whatever name you want

Comment: There could be any number of classes that implement that interface, but, more basic than that, you cannot have an implementation within an interface... only signature definitions

Comment: @bizzehdee Incorrect, see C# 8's [Default Interface Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods)

Comment: You might be looking for `this.GetType().Name`.

Comment: @canton7 didnt know that was a thing, that is absoltely terrible and not what an interface is supposed to be... terrible design decision

Comment: @bizzehdee I don't usually get drawn into comments, but what makes you feel that it's a terrible design decision to have [default interface methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods)?

Comment: @bizzehdee Considering you didn't know that default interface methods existed a few minutes ago, I find it quite surprising you have been able to assess the design decision so quickly.

Comment: @bizzenhdee im new to programming, but agree with you. Its not seems naturally...

Comment: The whole point of an interface within C# is/was supposed to be a definition. A way of being half-definition-half-implementation was always the job of an abstract class... so now, what is the difference between an abstract class and an intercface? What is to stop interfaces from being abused and used incorrectly? What benefit does this give other than helping developers be lazy?

Comment: "*what is the difference between an abstract class and an intercface*" -- abstract classes can have state, but interfaces cannot. Also, DIMs are explictly implemented, so they only show up if you cast the implementing type to the interface type. The benefit is that interfaces are no longer immutable: it's possible to add DIMs to an interface without that being a breaking change, but it is not possible to do that with "normal" interface methods. Note that many things which *should* be interfaces, such as `DbConnection`, are actually abstract classes for this very reason.

Comment: Helping developers be lazy is the primary goal of any development tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can easily be achieved using [`GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype):

```
public void ShowInfo()
{
    Type t = GetType();
    Console.WriteLine($"I am a {t.Name} and my weight is {Weight} kg.");
}
```

In the case of this:

```
public class HumanA : IHuman
{
    int IHuman.Weight => 5;
}
```

The output of `ShowInfo()` will be:

```
I am a HumanA and my weight is 5 kg.
```